# How to add background in the 2-pane preference screen?

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

in my app, i made a 2 pane preference screen following the API Demos examples. but i am not getting any background for the 
header pane. it is totally transparent.
do i need to add `imagebuttons` for the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Honeycomb but I assume View subclasses will have the XML attribute `background`, or `setBackgroundResource(int)`. Check to see if you can get the view/layout of the header pane to add a background to it.